# Mysql full text search for arabic

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, arabic, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to do a full text search on `utf8_unicode_ci` encoded tables using MySQL with MyISAM engine.

Here is the query:

```
 $sql = "select distinct u.userId,u.rite,u.link,u.reg,u.prenom,u.nom,u.pere,u.birthday,u.sex,
 u.mazhab,u.mere,u.martialStat,u.voted,MATCH(`nom`,`prenom`) AGAINST (':str' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 AS relevance FROM  users as u,users_responsibles as ur,users_delegates as ud where MATCH(`nom`,`prenom`)
 AGAINST (':str' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and u.userId=ur.userId and u.userId=ud.userId";
```

It searches for a certain user by his name, while being connected to a responsible and a delegate hence the `users_responsibles` `users_delegates` join

Now this works fine for only a handful of names, while it either gets 0 rows or an unsuspected result like returning 'mike' while searching for 'alice' (in arabic)

I've been searching for a while now and all the answers are from 2012 at most. I tried changing `ft_min_word_len` to 3 like suggested in seome comments with no luck.

I read many answers where it sais mysql fulltext doesn't index characters with >1000 byte encoding.

Is their any solution for this while still using MySQL ? If not, is their any other way to do this?

Comment: Do you restrict the characters which are stored in the database, or do you allow all kinds? There could be an issue with the encoding method.

Comment: And can you post that Mike/Alice example in Arabic?

Comment: I honestly scrapped the whole idea after I got frustrated (I asked this question 6 days ago) and went with a less accurate solution which is to split words and use `like '%word%' `. But I still would like to get an answer. Do you want to see the result of the query as it shows up in the browser, or as it shows up in phpmyadmin (utf8_unicode_ci encoded) ?

Comment: The mysql query itself would be fine. Yes, a copy from phpmyadmin would do it.